# How accurate is hacking in science fiction movies?

Tags: computers

I guess we all have seen someone hacking into another organization/person's computer/server with those fancy blue screen interfaces like in Die Hard 4, Iron Man, Matrix and so on.

Now I wonder, is it really possible to do that? And how accurately do those scenes represent real-life hacking?

Comment: Zero percent.  They use computers, that's about it.

Comment: I think this question is a bit broad to be suitable for scifi.SE. Also Die Hard 4 isn't science-fiction.

Comment: haha, sorry for the Die Hard 4 example. Was trying to find more examples :P

Comment: @Xeon: In theory this could be a really nice question, but as it currently stands it's just too broad to get complete and (at the same time) non-opinion-based answers. Try to narrow it down in a way that asks a more specific question.

Comment: Die Hard 4 is science fiction when you look at the tech...which is the whole point of the question. Die Hard's hacking is nonsense.

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens Mmm...I don't know that it is science fiction. It is possible to put together the "fire sale" (The term was coined for the movie) conditions and bring about that happening. Very doubtful that it could be done/coordinated with the few people they had in the movie, but the technology and theory exist and have been proven in small scale models/incidents. That moves it from science fiction to science "just really hard to do".

Comment: @JohnP science fiction does not have to be about currently impossible tech. I could write a story about 18th century chemists and as long as it was fictional call it 'science-fiction' in good conscience.

Comment: @cwyers - Granted, but the way the comment is phrased predisposes one to believe that he means impossible. I will concede your point, however. (Big of me, hey? :D)

Comment: [related: Why are computer hackers shown to either be geniuses, or show them doing it in fantastic ways?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1053/why-are-computer-hackers-shown-to-either-be-geniuses-or-show-them-doing-it-in-f/1054#1054)  Originally asked here, migrated to the Movies and TV StackExchange site.

Comment: Btw. [the actual answer to your question](http://www.smbc-comics.com/?id=1898).

Comment: Haha, guess we should be happy that hacking is not easy. Speaking of which, router just logged someone tried to use SYN Flooding on me, bugger..

Answer (score 23):

Not a lot of them are accurate -- they're meant to look cool, not realistic. Sort of like space physics. When you get it right, like *2001: A Space Odyssey*, it's a calm ballet. When you get hacking right, it looks like some guy typing. Boooring.

There's [one notable exception](http://www.securityfocus.com/news/4831) I can think of, however. In *Matrix: Reloaded*, when Trinity hacks into the power grid near the end of the movie, she uses nmap (a real unix application) to find a machine listening on port 22 (ssh). She then runs sshnuke (a fictional tool, maybe she wrote it herself) which attempts "to exploit SSHv1 CRC32". There was [a real CRC32 vulnerability](http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/2347) in some versions of SSHv1.

(In fact, you can use this to figure out the approximate date inside the Matrix. The nmap version was released in Feb 2001, and the SSH vulnerability was revealed in June 2001. So we can be sure it's after those dates.)

[image: Trinity's ssh hack from Matrix: Reloaded]

[Here's the scene](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0TJuipCrjZQ), you can see Trinity's terminal at about 0:03.

Some commenters have pointed out a couple of other bright points. In *WarGames*, which is otherwise a fairly un-realistic movie, there's a scene where [David programs his computer to dial all of the phone numbers in a few prefixes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AByemfK_qD4). This is a real technique (or rather, was, back when more interesting things were available via modem). Before the movie, this technique was called "hammer dialing" or "demon dialing", but since the movie, it's been almost universally called "[wardialing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wardialing)".

And although it's definitely not science fiction, as a programmer, I was remarkably impressed with [the Facemash scene from the opening of *The Social Network*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VSKoVsHs_Ko). All of the buzzwords (indexes, Apache, wget, Mozilla, Emacs, Perl script, etc) are used exactly right, and the patchwork way he had to solve the problems also feels very true to life. I could actually see reading the monologue on a programming blog.

Comment: "When you get hacking right, it looks like some guy typing. Boooring." - +100. I would be bored to tears watching myself hack. Unless they supplied Halle Berry as an added "difficulty", of course <g>

Comment: I wonder: Why is the flag passing to sshnuke not POSIX compliant regarding the number of dashes that need to be written before command line arguments? (POSIX requries 2, so it should be `--rootpw` not `-rootpw`)

Comment: ^ now that's some alien language you got there haha

Comment: There's also WarGames, which is also a fairly accurate representation of hacking, but perhaps not SciFi?

Comment: Hacking is boring? Well, what about that "hackathon" scene in _The Social Network_, with all the drugs and semi-naked hookers and all the crazy shouting? Are you telling me that movie is not _accurate_!?

Comment: @WillihamTotland: War Games is sci fi. WOPR is *massively* too "intelligent" --- it'd be conceivable for it to pass the Turing Test, something we can hardly do today, let alone in '83.

Comment: @bitmask I had never heard of anything called `sshnuke` until today.  And now you are telling it's part of the POSIX standard?  A smiley for the lexically challenged :)

Comment: @bitmask Windows accepts arguments like that.  I'm guessing a director or someone got confused when they tried to invent a new program.

Comment: @DVK It's only boring if you watch the physical stuff.  Which is why I loved [Hackers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hackers_(film)) - the computer visualizations are as fake as you can get, but if you instead think of it as what's going on inside their heads...

Comment: @WillihamTotland: Actually, that's true. War dialing is (or was) a real thing, and some of the social engineering in that movie was realistic.

Comment: @AndresF.: That scene is ridiculous, but as a programmer, I felt like the opening Facemash scene was the most realistic programming scene I've seen in any movie ever. I'll add those two.

Comment: @Izkata - any well written production quality Perl script accepts arguments like that :)

Comment: @Plutor I'll only agree to that inclusion if you agree _The Social Network_ is science fiction (as opposed to, you know, realistic drama) ;)

Comment: @Izkata "Ramon Sanchez: So, uh, what's your interest in Kate Libby, eh? Academic? ... Dade Murphy: Homicidal"

Comment: @AndresF.: Hah, that's a good point. Forgot about the "SciFi" part of the question.

Comment: @DVK A single dash (should) indicate a series of arguments, like `tar -cvvzf archive.tar.gz *`, while two dashes indicate the series of characters is 1 named argument

Comment: @Izkata: *should* being the operative word.

Comment: @DVK and there's not much typing involved, hackers use a lot of scripts

Comment: @anakata - script kiddies use a lot of scripts. Someone TYPES IN all that code :)

Comment: @DVK Yes, but what I mean, in movies, where the hackers are battling in real time against a firewall, and after furious typing they say "Im in", in that part, in real life, will be executing a bunch of scripts XD

Comment: @anakata - in real life they'd be calling some random drone telling them they are a middle level manager from satellite office who lost his remote access keyfob.

Comment: @DVK And sometimes its even easier http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2012/08/amazon-changes-policy-wont-add-new-credit-cards-to-accounts-over-the-phone/